# skiasharp vs skiashar.views xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to use skiasharp in xamarin forms or android. I found two nugets. Which of them should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably both packages. The SkiaSharp.Views package contains Views/Widgets ready to use, instead of having to set up GL contexts etc.

SkiaSharp.Views depends on SkiaSharp.